# According to those who do Shabbat's Hoshaanot on Sunday, what is done when Hoshaana Rabbah is on Sunday?

Tags: shabbat, chabad, hoshana-rabbah

There are different opinions about how Hoshaanot is conducted on Shabbat. Some say it and some don't. See [Nitei Gavriel Sukkot  Chapter 73, Halacha 18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46442&pgnum=347).

The Chabad Custom (as brought in footnote 31) is not to say any Hoshaanot on Shabbat, and make it up the next day, but not to go around the Bimah for that one, only for the Hoshaanot of Sunday.

In a situation such as this year and next year (5776 and 5777), Hoshaanah Rabbah falls out on a Sunday. This means that Shabbat's Hoshaana will already be said on Sunday, during the Hoshaana Rabbah service.

If so, are the Hoshaanot for Shabbat repeated before the Hoshaana Rabbah service is started?

Comment: I didn't say the Hoshanot for Shabbat during the Hoshana Rabbah hoshanot.

Comment: Art Scroll an Ezras Torah Luachshow that regular Hoshannah Rabbah are said. You would need to check with a Chabad Rav to see what their minhag would be.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the weekly ['Hiskashrus' magazine - issue 1161 - 19 Tishrei 5777](http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=12784&CategoryID=2106)

In the 'weekly calendar' section - which deals with the customs pertaining to the week to come - the following is written regarding the Hoshanot

> :הושענות
>
> מוציאים את כל ספרי-התורה שבהיכל, ועומדים עמם ליד הבימה. אומרים(29) את ז'
>   ההושענות, ‏

then in footnote 29:

> י"א שהבחינו בהו"ר תשנ"ב (שחל ביום א' כבשנה זו) שהרבי אמר תחילה את ההושענא שהיתה אמורה להיות בש"ק 'אדמה מארר', כמ"ש בס' המנהגים לגבי כל
>   יום א' שאחרי שבת חוה"מ, שצריך לומר בתחילת ההושענות את ההושענא דיום
>   השבת. ‏

So inside - it only refers to the hoshanot which are said on Hoshana Raba. However, the footnote mentions that some say that in the year 5752 (where Hoshana Raba also fell on a Sunday) they saw the Rebbe first complete the Hoshanot of Shabbat and only then continued with the Hoshanot of Hoshana Raba.

So although that still seems rather inconclusive, it seems that the general consensus is not to say the Hoshanot from shabbat in such a kviut. (from the fact that the author decided to not to include this direction inside the instructions themselves but only in a footnote)

Comment: Is that quote saying that אדמה מארר would have been said on Shabbat? I might be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes that's correct, אדמה מארר would have been said on Shabbat (that's the Hoshanot of the 6th day of Succot)

Comment: Maybe this is a different-Nusach issue, but I've never seen אדמה מארר said on any day but the 7th (ie. Hoshana Rabba).